# Where is the iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support install directory?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4, installation

I am in China, the `iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support` & `old version simulator` downloading will cause me about 2~3 days, because there is no any apple's host in China, the networking is very very terrible.

I usually backup the simulator SDK before updating xcode, it is located at  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs` directory. After updated xcode, I will restore the directory to install old SDK quickly.

Now, I want to know there is the `iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support` directory. I'm going to try to backup it. I know it maybe not work but I want to have a try.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think its located @

> Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications